# Sharelib error-[User: oozie is not allowed to impersonate oozie]

Tags: oozie

Executed the command "sudo -u oozie ./bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:54310 -locallib oozie-sharelib-4.1.0.tar.gz"

Iam getting the error "Error: E0902: Exception occured: [User: oozie is not allowed to impersonate oozie]" when trying to execute sharelib command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In core-site.xml in hadoop conf, change value as

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

And restart hadoop services and try again

Comment: can you share core-site.xml and oozie-site.xml

Comment: Have you restarted all the daemons ?

Comment: please give ur mail id. I will send the core-site.xml and oozie-site.xml. which daemons to start. Please tell me

Comment: when i put jps the output is 
40756 Jps
39984 JobTracker
39604 NameNode
39746 DataNode
40151 TaskTracker
39900 SecondaryNameNode

Comment: are you using Hadoop version 1

Comment: can you share your mail

Comment: valli@amitysoft.com